# Unable to read Active Directory credentials from Hashicorp vault AD secrets engine

Tags: active-directory, ldap, hashicorp-vault

When I try to read credentials(i.e vault read ad/creds/poc.test) of a service account I get the following error

**Error reading ad/creds/poc.test: Error making API request.
URL: GET http://52.4.16.119:8200/v1/ad/creds/poc.test
Code: 500. Errors:
* 1 error occurred:
        * LDAP Result Code 53 "Unwilling To Perform": 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0**

If anyone can crack , Thanks in Advance
I

Comment: According to this, you need to use LDAPS, not plain LDAP: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/4902

Comment: Ya, it tried even in that way, where I am facing an issue "Network Error".
Reference : https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/6110

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two issues then:

1. You need to use LDAPS.
2. If you're getting a "network error" when you use LDAPS, then you have to get that fixed first. That specific error ("connection reset by peer"), means that the connection was opened, but specifically rejected by the other side. There is nothing you can do to fix that. You will have to get the administrators of your Active Directory to fix that.

Comment: Its a Cloud machine.So,I only need to do that. What exactly I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit confusing with the ldap protocol, I tested ldaps to AD, and it bails out. The options to set **in vault** are:

```
url=ldap://ad.example.com:PORT
starttls=true
```